# TextEditingController doesnot change text of TextEdit at Web. May be other solution for EditText?

Tags: flutter, flutter-web

When the user edit text at TextEdit and then put new text by TextEditController, then the previous text was appear. Its about TextField and TextFormField. Its appear not at all tim but I cannt find out  reason of it.
Its cann be uset at that time.

[image]

But may be its have a any simple other solution? I need only workable text edit field.

May be other widget? Any suggestion will be accepted with appreciate.

It will be solved, iit have a post at github:
https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/41376

but may be it have a simple solution/any replacement for use it now?

flutter --version is:

Flutter 1.10.7-pre.23 • channel master • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision e0247442d0 (25 hours ago) • 2019-09-26 02:49:41 -0400
Engine • revision 3713ecf107
Tools • Dart 2.6.0 (build 2.6.0-dev.2.0 c6a14f4459)

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  int _counter = 0;
  TextEditingController myTextController = TextEditingController();
  var rnd = new Random();

  void _incrementCounter() {
    setState(() {
      _counter++;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            TextField(
              controller: myTextController,
            ),
            Text(
              'You have pushed the button this many times:',
            ),
            Text(
              '$_counter',
              style: Theme.of(context).textTheme.display1,
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
        onPressed:
//        _incrementCounter,

            () {
          setState(() {
            myTextController.text = rnd.nextInt(1000000000).toString();
          });
        },
        tooltip: 'Increment',
        child: Icon(Icons.add),
      ), // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
  }
}
```

**update 01/10/19: question was solved at [How to insert two action at one button OnPress - delete widget and create it by new?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58167577/how-to-insert-two-action-at-one-button-onpress-delete-widget-and-create-it-by/58167736#58167736)**

Comment: Hey man, i am also facing this kind of problem in my flutter web , but when you check flutter.io then you probably check there flutter_web is currently in progress and not for production use. So my urge to don't use right now for production.

Comment: I try to use not flutter_web, but current version Flutter and build for Web, if I right understand you. Add that information at post. And - yes, its in technical preview by now, but I tryed to use and test, why not.

Comment: Some of library is still not supported in flutter web and i understand you are working in normal material.dart package but still there are so many changes remaining in flutter web part like http, TextField

Comment: yes, but developers are making update very fast